# Do not evaluate the diagonal of a matrix Python

Tags: python, matrix

I am making a program that compares the elements `A[i,j]` with `A[j,i]`, if it is true once that `A[i,j] = A[j,i]= 1`, the matrix will not be antisymmetric. In the comparison, the elements `A[i,j]` where `i=j` (diagonal of the matrix) should not be evaluated.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,1]])
for i in range (0,2):
  for j in range (0,2):
      if  A[i,j] ==1  and A[i,j] == A[j,i]:
        print('A is not antisymmetric')
        antisymmetric = False
        break
```

I have tried to add the condition `i != j` to not evaluate the diagonal, but it has not worked

Comment: Using the condition `A[i,j] ==1  and A[i,j] == A[j,i] and i != j` in the if statement seems to work for me, what should the expected output be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I have tried to add the condition i != j to not evaluate the diagonal, but it has not worked" We can only possibly help you with code that we can actually see, and we can only possibly explain problems that are actually described to us. **How** did you try to add the condition? What **did happen** when you tried that, and **how is that different** from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Separately: what values do you expect to be contained in `range(0, 2)`? Please test this expectation. Were you correct? Do you see how this causes a separate bug in the code?

Comment: This is a simple typo isn't it? What did you expect from the condition `A[i,j] == 1 and A[i,j] == A[j,i]` - that's going to be `True` at least once if there's a `1` in the matrix on the diagonal, or on a mirrored coordinate

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your  original example had a typo, as you were checking for values of the matrix to be literally `1`, which is not relevant to the matrix being antisymmetric?

You were after:

```
import numpy as np


def is_antisymmetric(a):
  r, c = a.shape
  if r != c:
      return False
  for i in range(r):
      for j in range(c):
          if a[i, j] != -a[j, i] and j != i:
              return False
  return True


print(is_antisymmetric(np.array(
    [[1,0,-1], [0,0,0], [1,0,1]]
)))
```

Or, briefer:

```
def is_antisymmetric(a):
  return (
      (s := a.shape[0]) == a.shape[1] and 
      (all(a[i, j] == -a[j, i] or j == i for i in range(s) for j in range(s)))
  )
```